# PHP + jQuery add class when changed url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class

I need to add sorting to my page but the class is not adding to active sorting selection...

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="menusel active" name="hlavni" onclick="deleteClass()">
        <a href="?sort=hlavni">Hlavní nástěnka</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menusel" name="date" onclick="deleteClass()">
        <a href="?sort=date">Nejnovější</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menusel" name="dulezite" onclick="deleteClass()">
        <a href="?sort=dulezite">Nejdůležitější</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menusel" name="hledane" onclick="deleteClass()">
        <a href="?sort=hledane">Nejhledanější</a>
    </li>
    <?php
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];
        echo "<script language='jscript'>
        $('$sort').addClass('active');
        </script>";
    ?>
    <script language="jscript">
        function deleteclass() {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
        }
    </script>
    <div style="float: right; margin-left: 100px;">
        <h1 style="font-family: Helvetica; margin-right: 50px">Nástěnka</h1>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: which class is not adding.. Why you used "$sort" in $('$sort').addClass('active');

Comment: cover your javascript with `$(function(){` at start and `});` at end, which is you are echoing through `php`

Comment: Because as far as I know I can't use the url like "localhost/?sort=date" with javascript only and when I tried to use it without changing url it wouldn't sort the content of the page...

Comment: Your are not able to find an element by this code that's the issue as you are trying to find an element with name. add attribute `id` same as your attribute `name` and try this `$(#".$sort.")`.

Comment: Right now I've done it. xD It kind of worked and didn't work at the same time. xD It added the class to another element but didn't remove from the base one. xD

Comment: So I'll add to the javascript in php section that will delete it. ;)

Comment: While you are trying to delete active class you are going to call onClick event of anchor tag that's why it might be ignoring `li's` onClick event.

Comment: I cleaned up your introduction a bit so it's more obvious what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="menusel active" id="hlavni" onclick="deleteclass()"><a href="?sort=hlavni">Hlavní nástěnka</a></li>
                <li class="menusel" id="date" onclick="deleteclass()"><a href="?sort=date">Nejnovější</a></li>
                <li class="menusel" id="dulezite" onclick="deleteclass()"><a href="?sort=dulezite">Nejdůležitější</a></li>
                <li class="menusel" id="hledane" onclick="deleteclass()"><a href="?sort=hledane">Nejhledanější</a></li>
                <?php
                $sort = $_GET['sort'];
                echo "<script language='jscript'>
                $(function(){
                    $('#".$sort."').addClass('active');
                    var sort = '".$sort."';
                    switch(sort){
                        case 'date':
                        case 'dulezite':
                        case 'hledane':
                        $('#hlavni').removeClass('active');
                        break;
                        case 'hlavni':
                        default:
                        break;
                        }
                });
                </script>";
                ?>
                <script language="jscript">
                    function deleteclass() {
                        $('.active').removeClass('active');
                        }
                </script>
                <div style="float: right; margin-left: 100px;"><h1 style="font-family: Helvetica; margin-right: 50px">Nástěnka</h1></div>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna use get params to set active page u don't need to use js.
just use this:

```
<li class="menusel <?php echo $_GET['sort']=='hlavni' ? 'active' : ''; ?>" name="hlavni" onclick="deleteClass()"><a href="?sort=hlavni">Hlavní nástěnka</a></li>
```

same for the others links